# Point rollup to alternate file for import

Tags: rollupjs

### Background:

We have an Angular 2 application that we would like to start using AOT compilation for. Simple enough... except for one of my dependencies...

We use autobahn.js for communicating to our servers over a web socket connection. The issue is with loading this dependency in rollup.

The authors of autobahn.js have decided that for their browser version of the library they will host it in bower (fair enough) instead of npm.

We have a library that wraps autobahn.js with some nice utilities and handles other things for us. This is great because it is a universal solution. This library can be used in both the browser and in our node.js servers. (yay)

However the node version of `autobahn` uses `fs`, `url`, and other node specific features. (boo)

The `bower` version of their library uses the correct equivalents for the browser which is good.

In the wrapper we have an `import * as autobahn from 'autobahn';` (we use typescript) This works great in node, and also worked ok with some configuration in SystemJS.

### Problem:

How does one tell `rollup` (or the `rollup-plugin-commonjs`) to point to the `bower_components/autobahnjs/autobahn.js` file instead of the `node_modules/autobahn/index.js` file as it does by default.

### Current configuration:

```
import rollup from 'rollup';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

export default {
  entry: 'dist/iss/index.js',
  dest: 'dist/iss/bundle.js',
  sourceMap: false,
  format: 'iife',
  moduleName: 'statusMonitor',
  external: [
    'autobahn',
    'moment',
    'moment-timezone'
  ],
  context: 'window',
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true, browser: true}),
    commonjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    json(),
    uglify()
  ]
}
```

### Other Option:

Another option that would work for us is that `autobahn` also works as a global, and if we could patch rollup to use the global `autobahn` off `window` then that would work for our use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [rollup-plugin-bower-resolve](https://github.com/mjeanroy/rollup-plugin-bower-resolve) plugin which is analogous to node-resolve – if you include that in your `plugins` array *before* node-resolve (or use the `skip` option in node-resolve) then it should be able to find `autobahn`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's now on npm

https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js-browser

> The browser version is published to npm under the name autobahn-browser. Install with:
>
> `npm  install autobahn-browser`
>
> Note: the NodeJS version of Autobahn continues to be published under the name autobahn.